# How to hide color indicators that appear to the right of the Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, configuration, hide, indicator

Hello I need help bothers me this is minimal hahahaha. I would like to know how to hide these color indicators that come out to the right of VS Code, I marked them in green:

[image]

Thank you!